# Working with ipv6 and Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, ipv6, ipv4

I have the following problem, I work with Symfony and Doctrine, and I need to store both ipv6 and ipv4 in the same SQL varbinary field.

I want my entity to have a string ip property, mapped to my varbinary SQL ip field, and that when I persist the newly created/updated entity with doctrine entity manager, it automatically converts it into varbinary using INET6_ATON SQL function.

I read a bit about custom doctrine types definition, but I couldn't find enough informations to make it work by myself.
I think the proper way to do it is to create a custom type like MyIpType and override Doctrine SQL declaration but I do not have a clue of how to do this.

My first attempt was to override varbinary type definition, doctrine throwing an error 'unknown field `varbinary`' whereas I declared it in dbal symfony config as written in the documentation.

My second attempt was to create my own custom type but I was unable to make it work, without even speaking of overriding SQL declaration.

Could someone please help solve this problem?

I've declared my type as following:

```
<?php
namespace CoreBundle\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
  * My custom ip type.
 */
class MyIpType extends Type
{
    const MYIP = 'myip'; // modify to match your type name

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'MyIp';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return new MyIp($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value->toDecimal();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::MYIP;
    }

    public function canRequireSQLConversion()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Registered it in config.yml as below:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver        : pdo_mysql
        host          : "%database_host%"
        port          : "%database_port%"
        dbname        : "%database_name%"
        user          : "%database_user%"
        password      : "%database_password%"
        charset       :  UTF8
        options       : "%pdo_options%"
        types :
            myip : CoreBundle\Types\MyIpType
```

And mapping my two IP fields as this:

```
/**
 * @var myip
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ipv6_range_start", type="binary", nullable=true)
 */
private $ipv6RangeStart;

/**
 * @var myip
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ipv6_range_end", type="binary", nullable=true)
 */
private $ipv6RangeEnd;
```

Now I can't just understand what to do next, I've tried some custom things as shown in [this documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types) to override SQL declaration but it either do nothing either throw some doctrine unuseful stacktrace, as I digged down and it just wasn't enough to understand what was the problem and how to correct it.

I think I just don't understand how overriding these methods actually work, if someone could just enlight me by an example it would be so much appreciated!
Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Please post some code of what you've tried.

Comment: Creating a custom type like you tried, seems like a good approach. Please share your code and config, so we can help solve the issue you described.